# how to have mini search open on page load in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I'm new to magento 2. I'm not able to find a proper way to have the mini search area open once the page loads for the mobile theme !

---

I can see there are options for the mini cart like the following, but still not able to find the right solution for this !

```
<div class="mobile-search-form-container" data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
        "appendTo":".mobile-search-wrapper",
        "triggerEvent":"click",
        "triggerTarget":".mobile-search-icon",
        "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
        "triggerClass":"active",
        "autocomplete":"off",
        "parentClass":"active",
        "buttons":null}}' >
...
</div>
```

---

searched google and read magento documentations, but no luck till now. can anyone help me please?